# How to use ngIf in Multiple conditions in html and angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have to select drop in every click change the content how to use *ngIf  in Multiple conditions in html and angular "

Already i have to tried but not working

//Html

```
<div>
```

{{service}}

```
<div *ngIf ="service === 'Consult'">
  <p>Loren Gypsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make
    a type specimen book.</p>
</div>

<div *ngIf= "service === 'Data' ">
  <p>Loren Gypsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</p>
</div>

<div *ngIf="Digital">
  <p>Loren Gypsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500,</p>
</div>

<div *ngIf="Security">
  <p>Loren gypsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500, when an unknown printer took a galley of</p>
</div>

<div *ngIf="Cloud">
  <p>Loren gypsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.has been the industry's
  </p>
</div>
```

```
//Ts

services = ['Consult', 'Data', 'Digital', ' Security', 'Cloud']



}
```

Comment: what you want to do? `services` here is array and you are comparing it with string?

Comment: I need solution by i have use the select dropdown in every click goto change every click content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
  <mat-select (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of services " [value]="item">
      {{item}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

ts File:

```
onSelectionChange(event) {
 this.service = event;
}
```

in the template:

```
<div *ngIf ="service === 'Consult'">
  <p>Loren Gypsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make
    a type specimen book.</p>
</div>

<div *ngIf= "service === 'Data' ">
  <p>Loren Gypsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</p>
</div>
```

Comment: if you satisfy with this answer then mark this is a useful and correct answer.

Comment: Hii Upinder  i have to another doubt

Comment: ya tell me what is problem

Comment: i will founded in any one select the default in dropdown list working fine but content i am not solving how to visible the content with select list

Comment: Use [(ngModel)]:

<mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
  <mat-option value="1">One</mat-option>
  <mat-option value="2">Two</mat-option>
</mat-select>
Component:

this.service = 'Consult';

Comment: But how to possible way in (selectionChange)

Comment: use [(value)]="selected" in the selected variable you have a selected option assign this to this.service in ngOnInt.

Answer (score 2):

you can use two way binding(ngModel) in select like this

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="SelectValue" (ngModelChange)="hello()">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of array" [value]="item.value" >
       {{item.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

your ts file

```
SelectValue;
  array = [
    {value: '0', viewValue: 'DivisionOne'},
    {value: '1', viewValue: 'DivisionTwo'},
    {value: '2', viewValue: 'DivisionThree'}
  ];
```

and list

```
<div *ngIf="SelectValue === '0'">
  hello this division one
</div>
<div *ngIf="SelectValue === '1'">
  hello this division Two
</div>
  <div *ngIf="SelectValue === '2'">
  hello this division Three
<div>
```

here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qnz75p?file=app%2Fselect-overview-example.ts) for you

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to your problem.

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  services = ['Consult', 'Data', 'Digital', 'Security', 'Cloud'];

  selectedService: any = '';
}
```

User ngModel to bind **selectedService** variable to the view.

**app.component.html**

```html
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>

<h2>Select Service</h2>

<select [(ngModel)]="selectedService">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option  *ngFor="let service of services" [value]="service">{{service}}</option>
</select>

{{selectedService}}



  <div *ngIf = "selectedService === 'Consult'  ">
     <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. </p>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf = "selectedService === 'Cloud'">
   <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, </p>

  </div>

   <div *ngIf = "selectedService === 'Data'">
   <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.</p>

  </div>

   <div *ngIf = "selectedService === 'Digital'">
   <p>Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>

  </div>
   <div *ngIf = "selectedService === 'Security'">
   <p>The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested.</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Here is the full code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z4a1hp

Answer (score 0):

> Hi suresh,so for every change in drop down(select box) you need to
>   change the content right?

Comment: yes but i am use of ng if condition how to possible html and angular also need the clarification

Comment: <mat-select class="form-control" placeholder="Select Service" (selectionChange)="serviceChange($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let service of services" [value]="service">{{service}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>                                                                         
  serviceChange(event){

  console.log("service names", event.value);

  if(this.services === 'Consult'){
    this.Consult = true;
  }

}

Comment: How to possible for selected any one dropdown list and at the same time content also visible